# How to move from one Google Account to another?

Tags: gmail, google-account, paid-apps

I work at a company that has its own Google account , usually used for Gmail (not sure how it works and what is this service called, but they have it).

However, I've used it for Gmail and many other things, like purchasing apps and even created a developer account.

How do I move all of the things I've paid for (even the developer account, which costs about $25) to my private account? This was actually a mistake, as I didn't notice which account i'm logged in to, so I didn't even publish any app using this developer account.

Is it also possible to make the Google Plus account to belong to another Google Account?

I ask this in hope that if some day in the future I will leave my job, I will still have all of the things I had before.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that your purchases are permanently tied to the purchasing account. If there *is* a way to transfer purchases to another account, you'll need to contact Google directly. How you'd go about doing that, I have no idea. Either way, as this question seems to be Android-independant (It's about your accounts, not about using Android), I think this question may be off-topic.

Comment: dotVezz is correct: purchases are tied to the account, and are not transferable. As this is unlikely to have pure *technical* background, Google *might* make exceptions if you can convince them; but chances are rather low. Though I've heard the possibility should exist, I've never heard of anyone using it successfully.

Comment: How could it be that google allows transferring apps between developers accounts (see here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/checklist/3294213?hl=en&ref_topic=3450986 , though i don't understand the steps), but can't transfer other things?

Comment: @androiddeveloper, this is something that we can't answer. You'll need to contact Google for a concrete answer.